# Why are Scala's LazyList's elements displayed as unevaluated after being computed?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I am completely new to Scala. I've been playing around with `LazyList`s. Consider the following:

```
val fun: Int => Int = (x: Int) => {
    println("PROCESSING...")
    x + 1
}

val lazyList = LazyList(fun(1), fun(2), fun(3))
```

The snippet above prints `"PROCESSING..."` thrice, which indicates that all three elements of `LazyList` were computed. I found such behaviour to be rather unexpected for a lazy collection. So, I decided to print it:

```
println(lazyList) // which prints "LazyList(<not computed>)".
```

I thought it would print out `LazytList(2, 3, 4)`. (I'm not completely sure, but it seems to me that Scala's `println` works **for lazy collections** *sort of* like the [`:sprint`](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.4.2/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:sprint) command in `GHCi`, dividing the collection in two parts: the evaluated and the unevaluated one.)

So, here are my questions, concerning this code:

1. Why are no elements displayed as evaluated? If they are indeed unevaluated, what was this triple `"PROCESSING..."` thing about? If not, why does `println` claim so?
2. Why do we want `LazyList`'s arguments like `fun(1)` to be computed right away? Why do we cast away the `call-by-need` strategy when initializing? Are there any other cases where such a thing happens? Note that no output is produced when we use `map` instead of writing this down manually, as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `LazyList.apply`, any of the following work (without evaluating their arguments):

- `LazyList.tabulate(3)(fun)`
- `fun(1) #:: fun(2) #:: fun(3) #:: LazyList.empty`
- `LazyList.range(1, 4).map(fun)`

> 2. Why do we want `LazyList`'s arguments like `fun(1)` to be computed right away? Why do we cast away the `call-by-need` strategy when initializing? Are there any other cases where such a thing happens? Note that no output is produced when we use `map` instead of writing this down manually, as expected.

I don't think it is desirable that `fun(1)` be computed right away, but it follows from the fact that you used `LazyList.apply` to construct your list. `LazyList(fun(1), fun(2), fun(3))` is syntactic sugar for `LazyList.apply(fun(1), fun(2), fun(3))` and the type signature for that function is `def apply[A](elems: A*): LazyList[A]`. Note that the arguments of that function are not call by name.

So: why is `LazyList.apply` not defined with call-by-name arguments?

1. it is impossible in Scala to define a variadic function with by-name arguments
2. `def apply` actually comes from [`SeqFactory`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/SeqFactory.html) which is mixed into most collection companion objects. The `LazyList` companion object might be the one place in the collections library where the companion object `apply` isn't a helpful addition.

> 1. Why are no elements displayed as evaluated? If they are indeed unevaluated, what was this triple `"PROCESSING..."` thing about? If not, why does `println` claim so?

`LazyList` only knows when elements are evaluated because you forced them *through accessing them in `LazyList`*. In the case of using `LazyList.apply`, the following happens:

1. the arguments are evaluated when `LazyList.apply` is initially called
2. `LazyList.apply` calls `LazyList.from`, which is going to create a `LazyList` by lazily iterating through the intermediate `Seq` materialized in step 1

By the time step 2 has finished, the `LazyList` doesn't know that its contents are evaluated. Furthermore, the spine of the list is itself unevaluated.

`:sprint` in GHCi isn't a great comparison because it is much more omniscient in its understanding of when things are evaluated. It does this by crawling the runtime heap and printing `_` when it runs across thunks. By comparison, `println` just calls out to `LazyList#toString`, which is a regular Scala method.

Comment: I get it now, thanks. But why do we want it to work that way? Am I right to say that we **do not**, in fact, discard any of the work done, as the values get stored in the lazy list not as thunks (is that the right word in Scala), but as computed values?

Comment: Correct, we don't discard any of the work done. As for "why do we want it to work that way", I think this is a case of `LazyList.apply` simply not being useful - I can't really imagine any situation where the current behavior is useful at all. However, I also don't see how it could be easily avoided without further complicating `SeqFactory` and the collections library.

Answer (score 4):

Try with `#::` constructor

```
scala> fun(1) #:: fun(2) #:: LazyList.empty
val res0: scala.collection.immutable.LazyList[Int] = LazyList(<not computed>)
```

`#::` takes by-name argument unlike `LazyList.apply` which takes by-value.

Comment: Isn't it still weird that it doesn't seem to know that the elements were forced on construction? `lazyList.head` for instance informs it.

Comment: @som-snytt Maybe `apply` needs specialising to trigger [`state`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/9468b9abcda6955688804194c02fe11db8c78a38/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/LazyList.scala#L252) so `stateEvaluated` gets flipped? Probably `LazyList.from` has same issue as well.

Comment: @MarioGalic can you, please elaborate on this `state` thing? I'm not sure I'm ready to dig into the structure of built-in classes on my own yet :P.

Comment: @MarioGalic also, how does `print` work for different types? Is there some *generic algorithm*, or does it require every *printable type* to have a `print` implementation of its own. Could it really be the case with `println`?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are mixing 2 issues. The computation of the elements, and printing them. Take for example an easier case where you have:

```
val lazyList = LazyList(1, 2, 3)
```

The output of:

```
println(lazyList)
```

will be:

```
LazyList(<not computed>)
```

although the values are clearly computed.

When printing lazy list, we are actually calling [`LazyList.toString`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/LazyList.scala#L901) which calls [`addStringNoForce`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/LazyList.scala#L823). As we can see, as long as the [state is not defined](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/LazyList.scala#L825), we get the standard `LazyList(<not computed>)`. In order to get the state to be true, we must cause a call to the member [`state`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/LazyList.scala#L222). There are several ways to do that. On way for example is to call [`head`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/LazyList.scala#L237). Please note that this will cause the first element to be materialized, and not the rest of the lazy list.

For example. the code:

```
val lazyList = LazyList(1, 2, 3)
lazyList.head
println(lazyList)
```

will output:

```
LazyList(1, <not computed>)
```

and the following:

```
val lazyList = LazyList(1, 2, 3)
lazyList.tail.head
println(lazyList)
```

will output:

```
LazyList(1, 2, <not computed>)
```

The reason you saw the `PROCESSING...` output is not related to `LazyList` at all. If you call `fun(1)`, without the `LazyList`, you get the same.

Comment: Thank you for the insight on printing. Although, I am not sure I fully understand what you mean by saying that **"output is not related to `LazyList`"**. On the contrary, `fun(1) #:: LazyList.empty`, as stated in answers above, does not produce any output, although `fun(1)` has been explicitly written down. Isn't it fully function's business whether to execute its arguments or not? (The separate issue is that we cannot have an argument of type `(=> A)*`, so it's also *language design's business*, I suppose.)

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor, I was trying to explain why you saw the `PROCESSING...` part. Please note the difference, [`#::`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/LazyList.scala#L1109) expects an action, this is why it is not yet executed, while the apply method expects materialized elements. Therefore the `fun` method is called.